# Solve $\frac{2\, \cos{4 x} + 1}{2\, \cos{x} - \sqrt{3}} = \frac{2\, \sin{4 x} - \sqrt{3}}{2\, \sin{x} - 1}$ where $x$ is $-\pi \leq x \leq \pi$

Tags: trigonometry

I managed to transform the first part into $8\cos^3x + 4\sqrt3\cos^2x - 2\cos x-\sqrt3$
But I don’t have a clue what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

\begin{align} 
\frac{2 \cos{4 x} + 1}{2 \cos{x} - \sqrt{3}} 
&= \frac{2 \sin{4 x} - \sqrt{3}}{2 \sin{x} - 1}
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

Factoring \eqref{1} we get
\begin{align}
\tfrac{\sqrt3}2\,\sin(4x)
-\tfrac12\,\cos(4x)
+\tfrac12\sin(x)
+\tfrac{\sqrt3}2\cos(x)
-1
-\sin(3x)
&=0
\qquad
(x\ne \pm\tfrac\pi6)
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}
which is equivalent to

\begin{align}
{\color{brown}
(\cos\tfrac\pi6\,\sin(4x)
-\sin\tfrac\pi6\,\cos(4x))
}
+
{\color{blue}
(\cos\tfrac\pi3\sin(x)
+\sin\tfrac\pi3\cos(x))
}
-1-\sin(3x)
&=0
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
{\color{brown}\sin(4x-\tfrac\pi6)}
+
{\color{blue}\sin(x+\tfrac\pi3)}
-1-\sin(3x)
&=0
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
(\sin(x+\tfrac\pi3)
-\sin(3x))
-
(\sin\tfrac\pi2+\cos(4x+\tfrac\pi3))
&=0
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

which, by using sum-to-product identities, is converted to

\begin{align}
2\cos(2x+\tfrac\pi6)\cos(x+\tfrac\pi3)
-2\cos^2(2x+\tfrac\pi6)
&=0
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
\cos(2x+\tfrac\pi6)
(\cos(2x+\tfrac\pi6)-\cos(x+\tfrac\pi3))
&=0
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
\cos(2x+\tfrac\pi6)
\sin(\tfrac32\,x+\tfrac\pi4)
\sin(\tfrac12\,x-\tfrac\pi{12})
&=0
\tag{8}\label{8}
.
\end{align}

Comment: Wow! I mean, just wow. Thanks a lot!